# h264/aac encoded video not playing in Edge, but working Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, microsoft-edge, video-encoding

I am trying to encode a video to use in the HTML5 video-Element. However, it doesn't work in IE Edge on my PC. It does, however, work on:

- Chrome, Firefox
- My android smartphone (Chrome, Firefox)

I have two very similar files (one being the big bucks bunny trailer, the second being the video I'm trying to encode):

Picture: [Encoding-Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIFaa.png)

As you can see "1.mp4" is playing correctly, and "3.mp4" is not.

You can download the files here: [3.mp4](https://raichu.statshelix.com/encoding_test/1.mp4) - change 3.mp4 to 1.mp4 to get the other video.

My ffmpeg-commandline is this:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i in.mp4 -c:v libx264 -movflags faststart -profile:v baseline -level 3.1 -preset slower -crf 30 -c:a copy 3.mp4
```

However, I have also tried:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i in.mp4 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.1 -preset slower -crf 30 -c:a copy 3.mp4
```

and

```
ffmpeg.exe -i in.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset slower -crf 30 -c:a copy 3.mp4
```

The output of ffprobe of the result is (for the file that works):

```
$ ffprobe.exe 1.mp4
ffprobe version N-81045-g450cf40 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 50.100 / 57. 50.100
  libavformat    57. 42.100 / 57. 42.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.12.102
  Duration: 00:00:33.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 891 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 512x288, 770 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

and for the file that doesn't work:

```
$ ffprobe.exe 3.mp4
ffprobe version N-81045-g450cf40 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 50.100 / 57. 50.100
  libavformat    57. 42.100 / 57. 42.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '3.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.42.100
  Duration: 00:00:13.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2317 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2143 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 163 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction what the difference between the two videos is and how I can fix my ffmpeg command-line to play "3.mp4" in IE Edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`3.mp4` doesn't work here in Firefox, but if I re-encode the audio, it works:

```
ffmpeg -i 3.mp4 -c:v copy -movflags +faststart 3new.mp4
```

Comment: Yeah, I came to that conclusion too (just now). I don't know what's wrong, but apparently OBS produces invalid aac-streams :/

Thank you for investigating, I marked your answer as correct since it indeed was the audio.